# object from two-level array. causes Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

```
var data=[['a','1'],['b','2']];
```

This should be simple to make into an object

```
var Obj={data[0][0]:data[0][1],data[1][0]:data[1][1]}
```

But instead creates SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Why does JavaScript not see the array part properly when I try to construct an object in this way? When outside of the {} object

```
console.log(data[0][0]);    // "a"
```

I am puzzled as to why this is throwing an error as if there is a no-no rule I am missing. Am I forced into storing the data parts in temporary vars? like so:

```
var data=[['a','1'],['b',2]];

var t1=data[0][0]
,   t2=data[0][1]
,   t3=data[1][0]
,   t4=data[1][1];

var obj={t1:t2,t3:t4};     // no error
```

That would seem too restrictive for JavaScript I am definitely missing something here!

Comment: Your object literal syntax is wrong. You can't create an object literal like that. You'd have to create an empty object: `var Obj={}`, and then populate it: `Obj[data[0][0]] = data[0][1]`

Comment: @MattBurland, why is that?

Comment: Because you can't use a variable as a variable name in an object literal. Your second case isn't actually doing what you think it's doing either. You are generating an object that looks like this: `{t1:"1", t3:2}`.

Comment: I just learnt something new. Thanks, @MattBurland. Your comment above seems like a more descriptive and full answer to this question. Accepted answer just gives a solution but not an explanation.

Comment: @i--: Thanks. You motivated me to include an answer that hopefully expands a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iI think this is much simpler for what you want to do.

```
var data=[['a','1'],['b','2']];
var Obj={};
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    Obj[data[i][0]]=data[i][1]
}
console.log(Obj); // returns  Object { a="1", b="2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, it's not a valid syntax for an object literal:

```
var Obj= {
     data[0][0]:data[0][1],
     data[1][0]:data[1][1]
}
```

You can't use a variable as the name of a property in an object literal like that. In your second example:

```
var obj={t1:t2,t3:t4};     // no error
```

You get no error, but you also don't get what you expected either. If you look at the object generated, you'll see this:

```
{ t1: "1", t3: 2 };
```

In other words you created an object with properties `t1` and `t3`, not `a` and `b`.

You have to create an empty object and populate it using the bracket notation `[]`:

```
var obj = {};
obj[data[0][0]] = data[0][1];
obj[data[1][0]] = data[1][1];
```

Any time you want to use a variable as a property name for an object, you need to use the bracket notation. In other words this:

```
var t1 = "B";
obj[t1] = "foo";
```

is different from this:

```
var t1 = "B";
obj.t1 = "foo";
```

In the first case you set a property called `B` on `obj` to the string `"foo"`. In the second case you set a property `t1` on `obj` to `"foo"`. The object literal syntax is more like using the dot notation.

To make what you want to do simpler, you can loop through the array as in @Nikos' answer. Or you can get fancy and use `.reduce`:

```js
var data = [
  ['a', '1'],
  ['b', 2]
];

var obj = data.reduce(function(curr, next) {
  curr[next[0]] = next[1];
  return curr;
}, {});

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```